# HA-Proxy Layer4 connection, info: “Connection refused”

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy

I'm having difficulty in understanding how to properly configure `haproxy`

```
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# sudo systemctl status haproxy
● haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-12-01 10:12:16 CET; 5s ago
       Docs: man:haproxy(1)
             file:/usr/share/doc/haproxy/configuration.txt.gz
   Main PID: 33265 (haproxy)
      Tasks: 11 (limit: 72235)
     Memory: 41.0M
        CPU: 249ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/haproxy.service
             ├─33265 /usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -S /run/haproxy-master.sock
             └─33268 /usr/sbin/haproxy -Ws -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid -S /run/haproxy-master.sock

Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33265]: [NOTICE]   (33265) : haproxy version is 2.6.15-1ppa1~jammy
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33265]: [NOTICE]   (33265) : path to executable is /usr/sbin/haproxy
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33265]: [WARNING]  (33265) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for frontend 'apiserver' as it requires HTTP mode.
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33265]: [WARNING]  (33265) : config : 'option forwardfor' ignored for backend 'apiserverbackend' as it requires HTTP mode.
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33265]: [NOTICE]   (33265) : New worker (33268) forked
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33265]: [NOTICE]   (33265) : Loading success.
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 systemd[1]: Started HAProxy Load Balancer.
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33268]: [WARNING]  (33268) : Server apiserverbackend/k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 is DOWN, reason: Layer4 connection problem, info: "Connection refused", check duration: 0ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remain>
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33268]: [ALERT]    (33268) : sendmsg()/writev() failed in logger #1: Connection refused (errno=111)
Dec 01 10:12:16 k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 haproxy[33268]: [ALERT]    (33268) : backend 'apiserverbackend' has no server available!
```

This is `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg` :

```
# https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#haproxy-configuration

# /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Global settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
global
    #log /dev/log local0
    #log /dev/log local1 notice

    log /var/log local0
    log /var/log local1 notice

    daemon

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# common defaults that all the 'listen' and 'backend' sections will
# use if not designated in their block
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 1
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           20s
    timeout connect         5s
    timeout client          20s
    timeout server          20s
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# apiserver frontend which proxys to the control plane nodes
#---------------------------------------------------------------------

# https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/haproxy-network-error-cannot-bind-socket

frontend apiserver
    #bind *:6445
    bind *:45000
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    default_backend apiserverbackend

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# round robin balancing for apiserver
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend apiserverbackend
    option httpchk GET /healthz
    http-check expect status 200
    mode tcp
    option ssl-hello-chk
    balance     roundrobin
        #server ${HOST1_ID} ${HOST1_ADDRESS}:${APISERVER_SRC_PORT} check
        server k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1 aa.aaa.aaa.aa:46000 check
```

This is the output of `sudo ip -4 -c address show` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# sudo ip -4 -c address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    altname enp0s18
    altname ens18
    inet aa.aaa.aaa.aa/19 brd hh.hhh.hhh.hhh scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.30/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Port Range :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   60999
```

Empty Output of `ss -tnl |grep 46000` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~# ss -tnl | grep 46000
root@k8s-eu-1-control-plane-node-1:~#
```

How to correctly configure haproxy?

Comment: `connection refused` indicates that nothing is listening on the configured port on the target server.

Comment: Please run `ss -tnl |grep 46000` on the backend server and edit the output into your question.

Comment: Hi @GeraldSchneider! Thank you for helping. Empty ouput. I updated my question above

Comment: Well, that confirms it. Nothing is running that would be listen on that port. What did you expect there?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider This is actually my problem: how to properly define the frontend and backend ports, based on what is indicated here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/blob/main/docs/ha-considerations.md#haproxy-configuration

Comment: The backend port is defined by whatever you want to access via the proxy. The frontend port is defined by what is the most useful in that case. That can't be generalized.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I changed the port number from 5 digits port to 4 digits port and it worked.
Ex: frontend apiserver
bind *:45000 --> bind *:4500